# Trying to clip beginning and ending of clips without loosing quality. Using lossless running into issues

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, video, lossless, snipping

So I have a video file or several actually.

```
23.769 fps
1080p 
Hvec h265 mkv
```

I'm trying to clip the beginning and ending. It has advertisements I don't want. I have successfully done this using losslesscut?

The finished product changed the fps to 25.79 And bitrate according to right click windows 11 properties. The video seems fine but not sure as I did not watch it entirely.

The other issue is where I set to clip at the beginning doesn't show up properly. It still shows some ads when played. In the program it shows the desired play. So I had to adjust and export a few times to get it right.

Any suggestions with this or an alternative solution? Also did it actually change the fps? Because I heard that it's a glitch? A fix maybe. Thanks!

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Exchange! typically, you should include any command(s) that you used to attempt a solution, as we have no way of seeing when/if you could be something in a different way. I have a hunch about what's going on but I want to see what you tried before I write an answer. thx :-)